# Drop duplicates if timestamps are closed

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe with "log" information about who is working, in which task and at what time he/she started to work:

```
 index |    Entrance time   | Name | Last name | Employee_ID  | Task
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
   0   |2000-01-01 00:00:00 | John |  Fischer  |    001       | Maintenance
   1   |2000-01-01 00:04:30 | John |  Fischer  |    001       | Development
   2   |2000-01-01 00:04:30 | Bob  |  Conrad   |    002       | Maintenance
   3   |2000-01-01 00:10:00 | Mary |  Smith    |    003       | Multitasking
   4   |2000-01-01 00:09:30 | John |  Fischer  |    001       | Maintenance
   5   |2000-01-01 00:15:30 | John |  Fischer  |    001       | Maintenance
   6   |2000-01-02 00:04:30 | Bob  |  Conrad   |    002       | Maintenance
   7   |2000-01-02 00:10:00 | Mary |  Smith    |    003       | Multitasking
```

Then I would like to eliminate duplicates if entrance time difference between the one we are looking and the rest is lower than  10 minutes and if the task and name are the same. So the resulting dataframe should be:

```
 index |    Entrance time   | Name | Last name | Employee_ID  | Task
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
   0   |2000-01-01 00:00:00 | John |  Fischer  |    001       | Maintenance
   1   |2000-01-01 00:04:30 | John |  Fischer  |    001       | Development
   2   |2000-01-01 00:04:30 | Bob  |  Conrad   |    002       | Maintenance
   3   |2000-01-01 00:10:00 | Mary |  Smith    |    003       | Multitasking
   5   |2000-01-01 00:15:30 | John |  Fischer  |    001       | Maintenance
   6   |2000-01-02 00:04:30 | Bob  |  Conrad   |    002       | Maintenance
   7   |2000-01-02 00:10:00 | Mary |  Smith    |    003       | Multitasking
```

I have used *drop_duplicates(subset=["Name", "Last name", "Task"])*, but I dont know how to apply the time condition to compare each row with the rest ones.

Hope you can help me, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the calculation of time difference, this might help you. However, you also need to apply your conditions based on duplication cases.

```
# Make df sequential in ["Name", "Last name", "Task"]
df.sort_values(["Name", "Last name", "Task"], inplace=True)

# Compute time difference 
temp = df['Entrance time'] - df['Entrance time'].shift()

# converts the difference in terms of minutes (taking into account absolute values)
df['diff_mins'] = temp.abs() /np.timedelta64(1,'m')
```

The output:

```
2  2  2000-01-01 00:04:30  Bob   Conrad   2  Maintenance    nan
6  6  2000-01-02 00:04:30  Bob   Conrad   2  Maintenance   1440
1  1  2000-01-01 00:04:30  John  Fischer  1  Development   1440
0  0  2000-01-01 00:00:00  John  Fischer  1  Maintenance      4.5
4  4  2000-01-01 00:09:30  John  Fischer  1  Maintenance      9.5
5  5  2000-01-01 00:15:30  John  Fischer  1  Maintenance      6
3  3  2000-01-01 00:10:00  Mary  Smith    3  Multitasking     5.5
7  7  2000-01-02 00:10:00  Mary  Smith    3  Multitasking  1440
```